# User authentication for Node.js website

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I am building a website based on Node.js.

The approach that I am following to ensure safety of the APIs is as follows:

- The user **signs up with email and password**.
- On successfull signup and login, the client **receives a random generated token**
- It **stores the token in local storage** and **passes the token as header in all subsequent requests**.
- For every subsequent request the server **checks the token and validates the user**.
- Once the user logs out,the **token stored in client's local storage gets deleted**
- The user gets a **new token when he logs in again**.

Is the above approach good enough?Please suggest better ways if any.

Also I have seen people using passport-local for authentication purpose.
How can **passport-local** help in the above way of authentication?

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good approach because of many reasons. For example:

1. In your approach, the user will not be able to log in from two browsers (Mobile+Desktop) at the same time.
2. It's very easy to steal a localStorage data by XSS attack. If you use server only Cookie, it's much harder.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of random tokens, it would be better to use Json Web Token (https://jwt.io/introduction/). This would give you the easy way to verify the token is valid (the tokens are signed and has expiration time).